# No template found for UrlController#create, rendering head :no_content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a rails app where the user can submit a url through a form input into my postgresql database but it doesn't seem to be submitting into the database at all, it's not giving me errors either. The only thing it is giving me when a user posts a url is :

No template found for UrlController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 75ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)

So the way it works is:
User makes get request to '/url', they get a form where they type a url (ex: 'google.com') and this form posts to '/url'

In my UrlController I have:

```
class UrlController < ApplicationController
def index
    @url = Url.all
end
def create
    puts params[:url]
    Url.new(url: "foo") 
end
```

end

Here is what my postgres url database looks like:

```
header_parser2_development=# \dt
                List of relations
 Schema |         Name         | Type  |  Owner  
--------+----------------------+-------+---------
 public | ar_internal_metadata | table | minimoe
 public | schema_migrations    | table | minimoe
 public | tags                 | table | minimoe
 public | urls                 | table | minimoe
(4 rows)
```

and the url model:

```
header_parser2_development=# SELECT * FROM urls;
 id | url | created_at | updated_at 
----+-----+------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

Can anyone explain this, and how I can fix this? According to the docs this should be working and I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `Url.new` it only builds the object but you need to [save](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save) it in order to persist it into the database:

```
def create
  @url = Url.new(url: params[:url])
  if @url.save
    # Handle success
    redirect_to urls_path, notice: "Url saved"
  else
    # Handle failure
  end
end
```

Rails by default will try to render the template with the name of the action, in this case it is looking for a `create` template. So after creating the object you can to redirect it another action like `show` or `index` as I'm showing in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I switched it to Url.create and it now works perfectly